# kdb - qStudio multiple line execution

Tags: kdb

I'm using [qStudio](http://www.timestored.com/qstudio/) to write my `.q` files.

Now I found the following weird behaviour:

When loading two `.q` scripts as follows:

```
\l myFolder/scriptOne.q
\l myFolder/scriptTwo.q
```

These scripts runs flawlessly when executed individually (**CTRL+ENTER**)

But when selecting both of them and executing together (**CTRL+E**), I get either the following error:

```
'\
```

.. or the following error (when selecting *exactly* the two lines):

```
'nyi
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For running multi-line in QStudio, use semicolon for line ending. For ex, following 2 lines will not run together in qstudio using **Ctrl+E**:

```
   a:1
   b:2
```

`type error.

If you look in history tab, it sends command (a:1b:2)

So use

```
    a:1;
    b:2;
```

Now '\l' doesn't work with semicolon ending, it gives error. So use 'system' command for that.

```
  system "l script1.q" ;
  system "l script2.q" ;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer! Thanks :)